# How can I close all Selenium chromedriver/IEdriver opened windows?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

What I want is to implement this methods

```
public static void IECloseWindows(){  
}

public static void ChromeCloseWindows(){  
}
```

My dirvers are `IWebDriver internet;` and `ChromeDriver crome;`

I tried using `crome.close` and `internet.close` to close the driver, thinking that it will close all the windows but it don't work.

Comment: use crome.quit,it should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
driver.quit()
```

– It basically calls `driver.dispose` method which in turn closes all the browser windows and ends the WebDriver session.

In c# use `crome.quit` and   `internet.quit`

Comment: It will works if I used windowHandles and things like that? I mean (sorry my english), I have a driver that opens three different windows.

Comment: Yep, now I get what I want, using driver.quit();  thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
driver.close();
```

The above code can be used to close the current browser window. Where, '`driver`' is the Webdriver object.

`quit()` is a WebDriver command which calls the driver.dispose method, which in turn closes all the browser windows and terminates the WebDriver session.